# How do I animate a sidebar with all inner elements using TailwindCSS?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make an animated sidebar using only tailwind css (without javascript) ...

```html
<!-- tailwind -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Body -->
<button class="bg-hamburger w-[28px] h-[28px] bg-no-repeat bg-center m-[14px] ml-5 absolute top-0 peer" id="button_aside"> </button>

<aside class="grid fixed float-left top bg-[#F6F9FE] w-[0px] h-full peer-focus:w-[233px] peer:transition ease-out deley-150 duration-300 rounded-r-[25px] rounded-bl-[25px]" id="aside">

  <h1 class="text-[#6164E8] font-bold text-[13px] mt-8 text-center"> CHAT CHANNELS </h1>

</aside>
```

I'm trying to figure out how the new **peer** thing works.
I tried to mix **group** and **peer** together, but it seems like I can't do that..

**Question:** How do I animate the *h1* tag and other elements inside the *aside* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should animate the position property or translateX or scale, not the width.

Here's the result on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/PeSyGCsYF8

```
<button class="bg-hamburger w-[28px] h-[28px] bg-no-repeat bg-center m-[14px] ml-5 absolute top-0 peer" id="button_aside"></button>

<aside class="grid fixed top-0 bg-[#F6F9FE] w-[233px] h-full -left-[233px] peer-focus:left-0 ease-out delay-150 duration-300 rounded-r-[25px] rounded-bl-[25px]" id="aside">
  <h1 class="text-[#6164E8] font-bold text-[13px] mt-8 text-center"> CHAT CHANNELS </h1>
</aside>
```

I also removed some classes you had that were not real Tailwind classes and took out the float for you as well, it had no purpose in this context.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for your reply ! :D